# sqlite insert special characters

Tags: android, sqlite

```
db.execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO 'sms' (sms_id,text) VALUES (10,'__[ ]__|"?___'-@------@- '');");
```

run it on sqlite and show this line to me:

```
SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: INSERT INTO 'sms' (sms_id,text) VALUES (10,'__[ ]__|"?___'-@------@- ''); [ unrecognized token: "@" ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

i need a code to insert any text with any symbol

Comment: navidonline, use `StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql(string)` details decription [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)

Comment: and one more help [escaping string in SQLite](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/819d470eae5b939f?pli=1)

Answer (score 3):

Hello I think you should look at escaping qutes with double qutes `''` in SQLite

[Sqlite FAQ Site - Escaping quotes](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q14)

So in your case:

```
INSERT INTO 'sms' (sms_id,text) VALUES (10,'__[ ]__|"?___''-@------@- '');
```

Comment: this entry post by user and i cant change it

Comment: I don't understand. Please explain what you mean.

Comment: my app users send message to my server and i can not change message of them.i need a code to insert any text with any symbol

Comment: found my answer 

use:


    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO 'sms' (sms_id,text) VALUES (10,"''"+DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString("text")+"''");");


thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

There are usually wrapper functions like

```
  sql_execute('INSERT INTO `table`(a,b,c) VALUES (?,?,?)',1,2,3);
```

and those `?` question marks do the quotes and whatever else it needs to get your data in.

Not sure for Android but its in most programming frameworks.